# Why are there so many 2.1A usb chargers out there?

Tags: usb

I see a tonne of .5A chargers and then the next size is usually 2.1A, why not 2.2A or 2.0A or 2.5A?

Comment: Some of the latest iPhones and iPads require up to 2.1A current during charging ([Source](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3511)).

Comment: This is not true, there are plenty of 1A and 2A chargers out there. Marketing a charger as capable of 2.1A would earn you extra money with essentially the same device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next size up from 0.5A is 1A (often really 700 mA).

The reason 1 Amp and 2.1 Amp became standards are because of the popularity of the iPhone and iPad, respectively. Apple started using these values, and everyone else followed the money trail. Specifically,  Apple believed 2.1 Amp was the right rating for their iPad in terms of cost to power capability. I'm sure they had in depth reasons.

Answer (score 0):

USB port standards for PCs are limited to 100mA (500mW at 5VDC), so MOST devices designed to plug into a PC port will be designed around that limit. Apple on the other had drove the specs for charging their iPads to 10W (2A at 5VDC) so that the power hogs would not take forever to recharge. They made their charger rated for 2.1A as a fudge factor to account for line voltage variations. 2.2A or 2.5A would have had an exponential increase in heat and would have been pointless because the iPad charge circuit was limited to 2A anyway.

Once there were 2.1A chargers out there for Apple, other suppliers took advantage of their existence and began using that same spec.

Comment: Usb ports on PC are not limited to 100mA... and 0.1 to 0.4 amps more would not be an Exponential increase..........